# "We couldn't complete the updates, undoing changes, don't turn off your computer" windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

After Windows 10 restarted to install an update, the computer gets stuck in a loop of

```
 Getting Windows ready, don't turn off your computer.
```

and then after the update fails to install:

```
 we couldn't complete the changes, undoing changes...
```

I'm not too good with computers so would someone be able to walk me through fixing this situation? I'm using a Lenovo Edge 15 with Nvidia GeForce.

Comment: You can boot in Safe Mode ( [tutorial at 7Forums](http://www.7tutorials.com/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10) ). Can you tell us anything about the update Windows was trying to install?

Comment: I just had the same behaviour on a Windows 8 machine. I had to wait ~ 2 hours until it was completed but it works fine now. After a manual restart, I am able to install updates again. So you might just wait and see if it is not urgent.

Answer (score 0):

boot from the Windows 10 DVD or [Windows Recovery Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn938364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and run the command prompt in the repair options and run this:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\
```

*(replace C: with the drive where you installed Windows 10)*

This reverts all pending operations. Now you should go back to Windows 10.

Now copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to your desktop, zip it, upload it to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll take a look what is causing the loop.